how to calculate power of chi square test?
I'm having troubles understanding how to calculate the power of a test statistic, i am given the following problem:
given a random sample from a normal distribution where we know that µ = 0 and variance is unknown we want to test the null hypothesis σ^2 = 2 Vs the alternative hypothesis σ^2 = 3.
we use a 0.05 confidence level and find a critical value k, suppose we want to calculate the power of the test (β). my teacher said we could avoid using the non central chi square and just use a rescaling factor, by multiplying by 2/3 the critical value and use the central chi square distribution. However, online I found only power tests using the non central parameter. Do they lead to the same result?
